# Laravel 4 - copy a table from one databse to another

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I am using Laravel 4 to build a site that uses a large number of mysql databases, where each database has multiple tables.  The structure and organization of the databases is not within my control.

I need to be able to replicate a table from one database in another database at run time (the source database and destination database (and the specific table within the source database are dependent on choices made by the user).

Duplicating a table is easy to do with mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE database2.new_table LIKE database1.original_table;
INSERT INTO database2.new_table SELECT * FROM database1.original_table;
```

but I cannot figure out how to do it with Laravel.

I can easily access each database by creating their own connections ('mysql1' and 'mysql2') but I can't figure out how to construct the statement to use both. The following doesn't work

```
$success = DB::connection('mysql2')->statement('CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE database1.original_table);
```

because I am trying to access database1 directly without using the 'mysql1' connection, and Laravel generates an error saying that database1.original_table doesn't exist.

I feel like the solution should be obvious but don't have enough experience with Laravel to figure it out.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need each database to mirror each other exactly?  So you'll end up with two databases that are keeping in sync with each other.  Or will the database maintained by the Laravel app end up with more rows than the original?

Comment: The copy database will generally end up with fewer rows although it may end up with more, depending on subsequent actions / choices made by the user.  Initially I  will be using the SELECT to extract specific rows from the original.  I just showed it as SELECT * for simplicity's sake.

Comment: I had to do something similar to this in one of my project. I just created the backup of the whole database using a php script I found online and in the another database I executed the whole SQL statements from the backup file using `DB::unprepared()` method of Laravel.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean - I'll dig into this and see if I can figure out how to do it.  I would like to find a way to do it in Laravel as well though.  I have to believe that there are a lot of situations where people want to work with tables from two different databases.